# problem appending getJSON at the end of my webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, getjson

I've been stuck for days with an issue that I think is really easy for anyone.

I'm currently working on building my own "fake" professional webpage using glitch. I managed to put everything I wanted on it using HTML and I stylized it using CSS. So far so good, it looks like a real webpage.

At the end of this web page I want to put a "contact us" section and that's where it get tricky. What I want to do is use Javascript and RANDOM USER GENERATOR to replicate professionals that viewers can contact. 
Each professional (10 in total) has a picture and by putting their mouse on each profile, viewers can see the first name and name (maybe I'll add phone number and email address later) of the professional.

I pretty much got that part covered, here is my code,
professional.js :

```
$.getJSON( "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10", function( json ) {
console.log( json ); // print data in the console
var users = json.results; // results is an array of users

// store the "body" of our document inside a jQuery object
var body = $( "body" );

// loop through each user in our "users" array
for( var i = 0; i< users.length; i = i + 1 ) {
// store the current user in a variable
var user = users[ i ];

// we create a container for the user image and its data
var imgContainer = $( "<div class='img-container'></div>" );

// we create a jQuery object with an "img" element
var img = $( "<img>" );
// set its "src" attribute with a jquery method
img.attr( "src", user.picture.large );
// and append this element to our container
imgContainer.append( img );

// we create a jQuery object with a new paragraph 
var userData = $( "<p class='user-data'></p>" );
// set its inner HTML with jQuery
userData.html( user.name.first + "<br>" + user.name.last );
// and append this to our container
imgContainer.append( userData );

// finally we append the container to the "body" of our document
body.append( imgContainer );
}
} );
```

Here is the style used with CSS :

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body {
background: black;
text-align: center;
line-height: 0;
}

.img-container {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
}

.user-data {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: -120%;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.3 );

padding-left: 10px;
text-align: left;
color: white;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 24px;

transition: left 0.3s ease-in;
}

.img-container:hover .user-data {
left: 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to "import" my java to my document it "erase" my webpage. It's like it comes above it and hide all the content. I think that the problem comes from the fact that my .js file append the content in the "body" of my web page (body.append( imgContainer );).

So my question is, how can I append my .js project using getJSON into my webpage without erasing everything. I wish to append it at the very bottom of my webpage. It seems silly but I've been searching four hours and couldn't find any answer.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you insert the code?

Comment: looks like you forgot to share code, though you thought of that..

Comment: inspect in browser dev tools elements inspector (F12) and see if body has the other elements still...it should but don't really know how glitch works too much

Comment: Had some issues entering the code on this website, but is all good now

Comment: Glitch is basically a host to create web page, I managed to code what I wanted in my .js file but I just can't figure out how to append it at the bottom of my webpage